# understanding good practice for java rmi

Tags: java, rmi

I have a RMI application,
Basically every request from the client, created a new connection (on the server side) to the database, r n an SQL query and turned the data to a serializable class that was sent back to the client.

The user base of the app grew,and the request took a very long time to complete. the solution previous programmers came up with is to create a fixed size connection pool from the server to the DB, and every client's request used the oldest(the one used least recently) to run the SQL query.
My question is: what is the correct way to solve such a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say, pooling the DB connections is already an important step, since to establish a connection is expensive. Instead of implementing my own pool I would however use an existing and proven pooled data-source implementation such as DBCP or C3P0. They have many useful features such as varying size, automatic connection check, etc...

If it is the query itself that takes up too long, the optimization would be more complex than just that. Various approaches are possible and depend on the details of the situation, for example :

- Is there only one SQL query, always the same, as your question seems to imply ?
- Is the database read-only ?
- If not, are the modifications made within the same application or externally ?
- etc...

Possible approaches (I can think of right now) to reduce the request time :

- Caching of the result in the java app (but this is a vast subject...)
- Optimization of the SQL request
- Optimization of the DB schema, with indexes or deeper refactoring of the tables structure
- Reduce the amount of data sent back to the client to just the bare minimum (In case the network is the bottleneck)

I hope this helps. We would really need more details on the use case to give you a better answer.

Comment: thanks, thats really what i was looking for, btw, there are alot of differant sql queries,not just read only. and all of the call to the server are made with this 1 rmi application.